# Given a list of elements that evaluate to boolean values, how do I print the element name and not the value?

Tags: groovy

Lets say I have some variables that evaluate to either true or false:

```
firstValue = true
secondValue = false
thirdValue = true
```

And I put them in a list:

`def list = [firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue]`

I want to iterate through the list and check if each value returns true or false, if the value is true I want to be able to print the name i.e. firstValue

```
for (item in list){
    if (item == true){
        println("${item} is true")
    }
}
```

This is just printing "true is true"

Comment: Maybe just use a dict?

Comment: You might find this useful [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: you didn't put *variables* into a list. Lists, and other container types, contain **objects**. not *variables*. Variables are not objects. Objects don't retain any information about the names of any variables that might be referencing them. If *you want to associate a string object with some other object, then you have to write code that does that*. A typical approach might be to use a dictionary, or to use a tuple

Comment: why is this tagged with Python *and* Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list` only holds the values (true/false), so it's 'hard' to get the key back.

Consider using a dictionary, which holds some keys that you can [iterate](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) to show both the key and value

```
data = {
    "firstValue": True,
    "secondValue": False,
    "thirdValue": True
}

for key, value in data.items():
    if value:
        print(key, "is true")
```

```
firstValue is true
thirdValue is true
```

###### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETP3a9YclIQL70JvfYLSu@hSXCpTWR3FaT47WmsFTqnYR4zMy7ap3jO2Vm1eME3YJEJxKJ3O0zedHjjyTd7Lv6RojvA1Q5yEO2J3X8DVoCQGJ9@aXDeAFLE7aYl9S@p6g5OFHZULP40MkWtvi1DglqmTA05fwA)

---

If you really need a separate list of keys, you can use the following instead of calling `items()`

```
listOfKeys = list(data.keys())

for key in listOfKeys:
    if data[key]:
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Think I'll try figure out adding these to a dictionary instead and printing the keys this way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why the other answer was accepted even though it's written all the way in `Python` (???), but in Groovy you have 2 options:

1. in a `Script` you can grab the variables by their names like so:

```
firstValue = true
secondValue = false
thirdValue = true

def list = this.binding.variables.grep{ 'out' != it.key }

for (item in list){
    if (item.value){
        println "$item.key is true"
    }
}
```

2. You declare your data in a `Map` (how the dict is officually called in java) and iterate over those:

```
def map = [ firstValue:true, secondValue:false, thirdValue:true ]

for (item in map){
    if (item.value){
        println "$item.key is true"
    }
}
```

In both cases you'll get the following printed:

```
firstValue is true
thirdValue is true
```